# Other ways of 'disabling' a textbox against user input

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

in a DetailsView with the mode set to Insert, I had a textbox that is populated by an event, rather than allowing the user to type into it. Problem is, if I set the TextBox to either Enabled="false" or ReadOnly="true", it doesn't seem to populate the SqlDataSource parameter with the value of the textbox, which I need. Is there any other ways to stop users inputting data into that textbox, but not use Enabled/ReadOnly?

Thanks

Comment: Try to handle the keypress and Keydown events. But this is a clumsy approach. Or rather make it readonly only after setting the data into it

Comment: You could try using a label if it is not supposed to be modified unless you have some sort of presentation requirement that it looks like a text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it readonly with JavaScript:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly")
```

I'm not sure if this approach solves your problem with the SqlDataSource.